# How to determine if an upload connection is secure (ssl)?

Tags: tomcat, servlets, ssl, thrift

I'm pretty new to servers, so I'm sorry if this is an odd question.  I have an application that communicates with a server via a Thrift Servlet.  I've attempted to make the connection secure with ssl, but I want to verify that the SSL is working properly.  Any recommendations?

Notes:

I've heard that I should listen in on the connection, but when I try nc -l  it says that port number is already registered--because it's the upload port for thrift.

The thrift servlet was created by following this tutorial: http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/Thrift%20%26%20Eclipse%20%26%20JUnit%20with%20TServlet

Answer (score 2):

I like to use Wireshark (www.wireshark.org) to watch connections. You can watch the connection occur and verify that way that the SSL handshake is occurring.

This posting can help you determine what to look for in the wireshark output:
http://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL

For example, when I watch a connection to https://www.google.com in Wireshark, I'm able to see many packets going over the connection with a protocol marking of "TLSv1.2". This tells me the SSL connection is working.